# Android: Getting old image data from Image Capture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I have an android app, which is used to take images and send them via (W)Lan to a remote PC.

For this I have two functions to take images:

**One function for RAW images:**

```
fun takePhotoRAW(cmdDispatcher: CommandDispatcher) {   
    val rawImageList = ArrayList<Image>()

    rawImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
        rawImageList.add(reader.acquireLatestImage())
    }, null)


    val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply {
        addTarget(rawImageReader.surface)
    }

    setSingleCaptureRequestSettings(captureRequest)

    session.captureSingleRequest(captureRequest.build(), cameraExecutor, object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureStarted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, timestamp: Long, frameNumber: Long) {
            super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber)
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                logger.log("Capturing RAW image...")
            }
        }

        override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)

            var cnt = 0
            while (rawImageList.size < 1) {
                runBlocking {
                    delay(10)
                }
                if (cnt++ > 100) break
            }

            if (rawImageList.size > 0) {
                val dngCreator = DngCreator(characteristics, result)
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

                dngCreator.writeImage(stream, rawImageList.first())
                rawImageList.first().close()
                rawImageList.clear()
                logger.log("RAW Image Captured. Sending to client...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendImageToClient(stream.toByteArray(), NetworkCommandTypeEnum.IMAGERAW)
                }
            } else {
                logger.log("RAW Image Capture failed...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendFailedCommand()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**and one for JPEG images:**

```
fun takePhotoJPEG(cmdDispatcher: CommandDispatcher) {
    val jpegImageList = ArrayList<Image>()

    jpegImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
        jpegImageList.add(reader.acquireLatestImage())
    }, null)


    val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply {
        addTarget(jpegImageReader.surface)
    }

    setSingleCaptureRequestSettings(captureRequest)

    session.captureSingleRequest(captureRequest.build(), cameraExecutor, object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureStarted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, timestamp: Long, frameNumber: Long) {
            super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber)
            logger.log("Capturing JPEG image...")
        }

        override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)

            var cnt = 0
            while (jpegImageList.size < 1) {
                runBlocking {
                    delay(10)
                }
                if (cnt++ > 100) break
            }

            if (jpegImageList.size > 0) {
                val jpegbuffer = jpegImageList.first().planes[0].buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(jpegbuffer.remaining())

                jpegbuffer.get(bytes, 0, jpegbuffer.remaining())
                jpegImageList.first().close()
                jpegImageList.clear()
                logger.log("JPEG Image Captured. Sending to client...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendImageToClient(bytes, NetworkCommandTypeEnum.IMAGEJPEG)
                }
            } else {
                logger.log("JPEG Image Capture failed...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendFailedCommand()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Each of those functions works fine individually, however for some reason if I take images in the following order:

1. RAW
2. JPEG
3. RAW

The second RAW image contains the same image data as the first. At this point I have to restart the app, in order to be able to take different RAW image again. JPEG images will still work fine.

If however I take images in this order:

1. RAW
2. RAW
3. RAW

I get three different RAW images as expected. Somehow taking JPEG images messes up the capture for raw images...

**Edit:** (trying to answer comment questions):

The calling method of the two function looks like this:

```
private fun takePhoto(type: String) {
    when (type) {
        "RAW" -> cameraManager.takePhotoRAW(this)
        "JPEG" -> cameraManager.takePhotoJPEG(this)
        else -> return
    }
}
```

The minimum time between images is basically the time an image takes to be sent over the network to the client: Client machine requests an image, as soon as it has received the image it requests the next. However, I can also trigger the requests manually and the time between calling the two functions doesn't seem to have an effect (tested from immediately to 10+ seconds).

Comment: Can you post your calling method code?

Comment: How much time between calling one of these functions? And do you call the next only when the the other has finished?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: Hmm. `rawImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(` You set this listener to two readers. But are you removing them at a time? Suggestion: set the other to null. Only one active listener.

Comment: @blackapps so you mean within `takePhotoJPEG()` I should set `rawImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)` and vice verca in `takePhotoRAW()` ? I'll give it a test.

Comment: OK, this didn't solve the issue. I'm considering simply merging the two functions into one and add the `Imagereaders` and set the `CaptureRequests` according to the requested image type.

Comment: A couple of your variables are not local to those functions. Can't you make them local? 'session'. and setSingleCaptureRequestSettings(captureRequest) is also called for both. Sorry.. i just write what comes in mind... i am not doing such things... if you follow remarks.. all at own risk.. ;-)

Comment: @blackapps sorry for the late reply and thanks for the suggestions. I have created a single `takePhoto()` method from the two original function and this seems to work. I had separate commands initially, because packaging both images into a single stream and slicing them up at the client machine was a bit of a pain. However, I guess this way the whole application runs a bit smoother.

Comment: Good to hear this from you. And late? I think you did all quick!